# Vue Router import not working with require

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, es6-modules, vue-cli

I'm setting up a brand new Vue 2 project. Due to compatibility issues with one of the libraries I need to use, I can't yet move to Vue 3.

I have a very basic setup at the moment, folder structure something like this:

```
/
App.vue
main.js
router.js

/pages
AboutUs.vue
Home.vue
```

If I don't use Vue Router, and just import the AboutUs page into App.vue and call its tag in the template, it displays as expected.

When I instead use the Vue Router to render it in the `<router-view />` tag in App.vue, I get the error message:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

I suspect that means I'm doing something wrong in the router but I can't see what.

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import router from 'router.js'

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/About">About</router-link>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

**router.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const About = require('../pages/AboutUs')
const Home = require('../pages/Home')

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: About
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  linkExactActiveClass: '',
  routes
})

export default router
```

**About.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>About</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: From the official docs, it looks like the correct form is `<router-view></router-view>` aka `router-view` is not a self closing tag. https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view

Comment: @kissu The docs show it that way, but it's ok for any component to self close in Vue CLI.  In fact, it's [strongly recommended](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended) to do so.  (This is not the case for in-DOM templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### es6 import

Try to use an es6 import instead of `require`:

```js
import About from '../pages/AboutUs'
import Home from '../pages/Home'
```

Then your route syntax will work as is.  This is because when you use `require`, you get the whole module rather than the `Component` export from the module.

-or-

#### `require`

Alternatively, if you wanted to continue using `require`, you would need the following syntax, using the `default` property of the module:

```js
const About = require('../pages/AboutUs')
const Home = require('../pages/Home')
```

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: About.default
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home.default
  }
]
```